# test some options separated with "|"

Tags: regular-expression

I have a string built with multiple option:value separated with |

the option:value can be one of the two:

```
[[:alnum:]]{3}:all

[[:alnum:]]{3}:FQDN
```

where FQDN is the DNS name of a host

for example:

```
647:all|1bc:all|d1f:all|vf4:www.host.com|vk4:all|k22:www.another.com|bbd:all|opo:all
```

how to build the regex testing this string match the rule?

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to test that the `647:all|1bc:all|d1f:all|...` string is properly formatted and contains parts matching the patterns you mentioned above?

Depending on how strictly you want to match the domain names, one part of that could (in ERE) be e.g.

```
[[:alnum:]]{3}:(all|[-a-zA-Z0-9.]+)
```

And a full line with multiple copies of that, `|`-separated:

```
^[[:alnum:]]{3}:(all|[-a-zA-Z0-9.]+)(\|[[:alnum:]]{3}:(all|[-a-zA-Z0-9.]+))*$
```

That would allow stuff like `abcd` or `foo..bar` in the domain name, even though they're not really fully-qualified or valid names. For a stricter test, the domain name part should probably be something like this: `[-a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)+\.?`

It would probably be prettier to split that string first and test the parts individually, instead of using a single big regex.

Something like this would print the elements that don't match the required pattern:

```
$ perl -lne 'chomp; for $a (split/\|/) { 
      print "mismatch: $a" if $a !~ /^[[:alnum:]]{3}:(all|[-a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)+\.?)$/; 
      }'   <<< '123:all|456:abcd|789:foo..bar|999:www.host.com'
mismatch: 456:abcd
mismatch: 789:foo..bar
```

Comment: @Kusalananda, you are right, i want to be sure variable is set correctly for further processing.

Comment: @DonJ, is that any better?

Comment: Without the stricter definition of the domain name pattern, the string `all` is included in the pattern and doesn't _need_ to be specified separately. It may be good to include it nonetheless for clarity.

Comment: @Kusalananda, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The following two-stage pipeline will print out all parts of the string that does *not* fulfil the criteria from the question:

```
tr '|' '\n'| sed -r -n '/^[[:alnum:]]{3}:[[:alnum:].]{1,}$/!p'
```

This uses a very loose/permissive expression for the FQDN: `[[:alnum:]._-]{1,}`, i.e. any collection of alphanumerics along with `.`, `_` and `-` (this means that the FQDN `---` is "valid").

The pipeline breaks the string down into multiple lines on the `|` delimiter and the `sed` expression prints any such line that does not match the given regular expression (`!p`, "print if not matched").